# как отправить картинку в php файл при помощи ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

я хочу передать изображение при помощи ajax в php файл под названием changeData.php

после выполнения данного кода вылезает ошибка

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'FormData': parameter 1 is not of type 'HTMLFormElement'.

```js
$('.photoInput').on('change', function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "changeData.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {photo: new FormData(this)}
    }).done(function(){
        console.log(123)
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">Photo</div>
  <div class="column">
    <label for="photoInput">Add photo</label>
  </div>
  <div class="column photoPreview">
    <input name="photo" type="file" class="photoInput" id="photoInput" placeholder="add photo" style="display:none">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ```data: {photo: new FormData(this)}``` тут ошибка

Comment: Если используете `new FormData()`, то в конструктор нужно передать элемент HTML-формы form, а не инпут. Потому либо передайте туда всю форму, чтобы объект `FormData` мог прочитать поля формы, либо просто передавайте значение инпута, вместо `FormData`, `{photo: this.value}` или с jQuery `{photo: jQuery(this).val()}`

Answer (score 1):

Если открыть документацию, то там будет список методов, которые есть у объекта (напр. https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/FormData). Нужно лишь найти необходимый тебе метод и посмотреть описание конкретного метода с примерами кода (напр. https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/FormData/append).

Теперь по теме. Если тебе нужно сделать это именно через FormData, то реализовать это можно следующим образом.

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="image" onchange="uploadFile(this)" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    
    function uploadFile(file) {

        const formData = new FormData()
        formData.append("file", file.files[0])

        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest

        xhr.open('POST', 'load.php', false)
        
        xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
            console.log(xhr.responseText)
        }

        xhr.send(formData)
    }

</script>
```

И далее в PHP уже работать с нужным тебе файлом.

```
<?php


if(!empty($_FILES)) {
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], realpath(__DIR__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . basename($_FILES['file']['name']))) {
        echo "Файл успешно загружен";
    }else{
        echo "Что-то пошло не так";
    }
}
```

Comment: не обязательно через FormData, задача получить фото в ajax, отправить его в php, и сохранить его в папке, а название фото отправить в БД

Comment: Вышеописанный пример как раз позволяет это реализовать. Просто дальше нужно получить название файла и его местоположение (сейчас файл по-умолчанию загружается в корневую директорию сайта) и выполнить запрос на добавление записи в базу данных.

Comment: console.log(this.value) в данном примере выводит undefined

Comment: Потому что вы пытаетесь получить свойство value у глобального объекта Window, которого у него нет. Чтобы получить адрес картинки в консоли нужно использовать либо json.parse(xhr.responseText) и получать картинку непосредственно с сервера, либо xhr.onreadystatechange = function() { console.log(this.value }.bind(file) и получить локальный адрес файла

Answer (score 0):

Конструктор FormData() принимает html форму, а не input.
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData